# Discrete Math confused on instructions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

- Using quantifiers and predicates. In each case you must specify the domain and define the predicates you use.
  a) For every integer $n$, $2n \ne 9$.

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, 2n \ne 9$$

is there more I need to do to for this answer, I'm not sure?

Comment: Your answer is correct but your instructor may have more strict rules about syntax. For example, are you allowed to use $\ne$ in your statements?

Comment: That's a thing I wasn't sure about either. like could it want it as the not symbol for example, 2n ¬= 9 ? or could it be like 2n ^¬ 9 don't think this one makes as much sense.

Comment: To be picky:  for all n, (n in Z implies not(2n = 9)).